# Got not sufficient privileges message in CMD when logged on as administrator

Tags: windows-7, command-line, privileges, mklink

I was trying to use `mklink` command in `cmd` (I have Windows 7 OS) I was logged on as administrator, but I got:

> You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.

I used the same command in Vista, it worked OK. Any ideas why it does not work in Windows 7?

Answer (score 37):

Try explicitly [running the CMD shell as administrator](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html).  If that doesn't help, then try the [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command.

```
runas /user:administrator "mklink args"
```

Quotes around the `mklink` command and its arguments are required.

Comment: Symlinks are too dangerous for a normal user. LOL. I wish I could understand the considerations behind this. :-(

Comment: My user is an administrator (there is no user called "administrator" on this machine.) but I still get "You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation."

Comment: This answer, although helpful advice in the general case, seems to be exactly the opposite of the behaviour I'm observing: mklink only works for me when my user is *not* an administrator. Puzzling.

Comment: what to do if you don't have a login password? it is asking for one and if I leave blank it tells me blank password error...

Comment: so, after finding out winblows broke the years and years old 'cd' syntax for cd /D, you get to type in the mklink syntax in the horrible contraption called 'cmd.exe' to find out you don't have privileges nad had to run as administrator first. Winblows sysadmin, the horror aaargh.

Comment: Didn't work. Instead I had to: `runas /user:administrator cmd`, and then in that new window, run the `mklink` command. Argh!

Comment: @JonathanHartley your administrator account likely has different name and your account is the admin, so when you runas administrator, you ironically switch from admin priviledges. Find your current (admin) account by `echo %username%`

Answer (score 16):

Type `CMD`, you will see `CMD.exe` in the list at start menu.

Right click on it, select "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 14):

In response to this not working for administrator accounts, I believe that [Configuring symlink support in Windows 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/os_fileservices/thread/e967ab01-3136-4fda-9677-e5ecaaa2f694#945a7cec-c138-4cb3-b9a7-adaabe3171a1) is relevant.

> After giving “Everyone” the privilege “Create symbolic link”, please reboot (or log off) and log in as a standard user, a user who is NOT a member of group “Administrators”. You should be able to create a symbolic link using mklink command in a directory where user has write permissions.
>
> The reason a member of “Administrators” cannot create symbolic link is because “Create symbolic link” privilege is removed from the filtered token since user is a member of “Administrators” group. Section “Access Token Changes” of article at link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx describes in more details on how filtered token is created.

Comment: Why does Microsoft always screw up?

Comment: @CoDEmanX, its complicated :)

Comment: Wait, so... where does one set those write permissions? The linked articles are not exactly the clearest to read through.

Answer (score 11):

First, make sure you've granted the "Create symlinks" permission to the relevant users, as detailed [here](https://superuser.com/a/125981/57697).

Bizarrely, the `mklink` command will not work for me if my user is an administrator. It gives:

> You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.

To make it work, I then need to either remove my user from the administrators group, or run `mklink` from a `cmd` which has been run as a non-Administrator user such as guest:

```
runas /user:guest cmd
```

(Enable the guest account if it isn't already)

Using this latter method, you'll also have to temporarily grant permissions for 'guest' account to modify the location you're creating the Symbolic link in, which in my case was my home directory, causing a flurry of error dialogs, but they seemed harmless.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work (I blame Microsoft). The `runas` command asks for the password of the specified user, even if the account doesn't have one. If you leave it blank (hit enter), it errors out. If the account does have a password and you type it in, then I end up with `the system cannot find the file specified`. Starting a cmd as admin, navigating to the target dir and creating the symlink with your own account suddenly appears so easy...

Answer (score 11):

If, for some reason, you cannot elevate your account to an administrator (eg. you're on a work computer), and you're trying to link a directory, try creating a junction instead of a hard/soft symbolic link. The source folder can be absolute or relative.

```
mklink /J linkedfolder sourcefolder
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me as I do not have admin on my work pc and needed to link cygwin directories and windows directories.

Answer (score 1):

In a <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (*Run.....*) box, type `cmd` and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to run Command Prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see the "Secondary logon" service isn't disabled.

Comment: As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users).

Answer (score 0):

Run "CMD" Command Prompt with "Administrator Privileges":

- Start > Search for CMD
- Right Click and chose "Run as Administrator"
- Click Yes on "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your
  device?"

And run you command again.

Answer (score -3):

If not installed, please consider installing Microsoft.NET framework 2.0 or the service packs that go with it.

It worked for me!