# Symbolic Link Directory (mklink /D) The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link

When I do this command:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyDocs\VSCode" "C:\Users\user\.vscode"
```

I get the error : "The system cannot find the path specified."

I run cmd as [admin](https://superuser.com/a/402520/300121).
I am [able](https://superuser.com/a/105381/300121) to create Symbolic Link Directory for others folders.
I have followed the recommandation on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987597/why-cant-the-system-find-the-path-specified-when-making-a-symbolic-link).
I am able to move to the `.vscode` with `cd C:\Users\user\.vscode` and to list its content with `dir`.

`C:\Users\user\.vscode`is a hidden folder.
I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Question: `ls` is not a Windows command, so how are you doing the mklink?

Comment: `ls` worked for me on a regular (not admin) cmd (maybe because I installed git repo : https://superuser.com/questions/1248999/why-does-ls-work-on-my-cmd-windows). I am doing the mklink by copying the command in my question in a `cmd` started as admin. (I am on windows 10)

Comment: I change `ls` to `dir` to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Try to first `cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyDocs\"` and then "mklink /D VSCode "C:\Users\user\.vscode"`. If that fails, I haven't found any reason for it, but you might try to unhide `.vscode`.

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Post it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work better :

```
cd "C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyDocs\"
mklink /D VSCode "C:\Users\user\.vscode"
```

Comment: but why it worked?