# Prevent Dropbox, Google Drive, Skydrive, files resyncing when reinstall operating system

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, google-drive

I currently use Dropbox, Google Drive, Microsoft Skydrive. They reside in these folders:

```
C:\users\fortune\dropbox
C:\users\fortune\SkyDrive
C:\users\fortune\Google Drive
```

First, I need to move them to another drive (D:). I plan to follow these instructions.
[Dropbox & Google Drive](http://keithrowland.com/2012/04/how-to-move-dropbox-and-google-drive-folders/), [SkyDrive move instructions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/move-skydrive-folder/3fa8e82b-2030-4327-bbe8-be27912515e3?msgId=aaea9657-b3d2-46a3-8a80-b003e4b90876).

Assuming the the move is successful, my question now is that I need to reinstall my Windows OS on C:. After I reinstall the OS and reinstall Dropbox, Google Drive, Skydrive, how can I prevent them each from trying to redownload all my cloud-stored files, and also redundantly upload all my files from D:?

Answer (score 1):

Before reinstalling them, create links using [`mklink`](https://superuser.com/a/125981/3463), such that they appear to be in the right place.

The default locations will be automatically populated with your files after installation, and there should be no redundant uploading either.

---

Example, as requested:

Let's assume we're dealing with DropBox. This will apply to the others too, but for convenience I'll explain just the one.

- Stop DropBox from running (I think it is a Windows Service)
- Move the data from `C:\Users\Fortune\DropBox` to `D:\Cloud\DropBox`. Don't copy, because the folder on the C: drive must no longer exist for the next step to work correctly.
- Create a directory junction* with `MKLINK /J C:\Users\Fortune\DropBox D:\Cloud\DropBox`
- Check in Windows Explorer that the junction is there. It should behave like the real thing.
- Start DropBox again.

What happens is you fool your OS into thinking that the folder on the D: drive is where it always was.

When you then format the C: drive, the junction point goes away, your data is safe, and when you install DropBox again, you just recreate the junction point *before* installing it, to make sure it uses the existing data. No duplication or re-uploading required.

**(I've typed this edit on an iPad with no access to Windows, so I hope the MKLINK syntax is correct.)*

Comment: I'm not familiar with mklink and tried to read the answers to the question you linked to but didn't fully get it. Can you elaborate a bit more conceptually what I'm supposed to do? Thanks.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: before I try this out, I'm wondering after I format C:, can't I just reinstall dropbox and specify the dropbox folder location to D:\Cloud\DropBox, and thus avoid having to create a junction point?

Comment: You can certainly do that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

After installation of Dropbox, it creates a folder inside 'My Documents' folder automatically.

So in order to prevent resyncing, just change the path of the 'My Documents' folder in the new installation of Windows, in such a way that the folder named 'Dropbox' is created in the place where u have kept the backup.

For Example,
if u have kept backup in D:\Cloud\DropBox
then the path of 'My Documents' folder should be D:\Cloud

After changing the path only, Dropbox should be installed and not before.

It worked for me perfectly.