# symlinks for admin users on Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, symbolic-link, privileges

On Windows you can create symlinks

- either if you start the programm, you want to create a symlink in (e.g. cmd), as Administrator.
- or if you give your user/usergroup the permission to create symlinks ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user?answertab=votes#125981) is an explanation, how to do this).

The second way is not working for me, when the user, whom I want to give the permission, is an administrator. Is there a solution for this issue?

Thx

Answer (score 4):

Hard link:

file:

```
fsutil hardlink create "file1" "file2"
```

or

```
mklink /H "file1" "file2"
```

dir:

```
mklink /J dir1 dir2
```

Soft link:

file:

```
mklink "file1" "file2"
```

dir:

```
mklink /D "dir1" "dir2"
```

Microsoft Windows 2000 Resource Kit :

```
Linkd
```

Sysinternals Suite Utilities:

```
Junction
```

view link:

```
dir <drive: or dir> /S /A:L
```

run application at administrator:

```
Runas /user:[Domain\]administrator CMD
```

Administrative Tools

Group policy object editor

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\
Create symbolic links <user name, user group>
```

Comment: Thank you for info about creating links, but it doesn't give any answert to my question.

Comment: @automatix Thx, I edit it.

Comment: I think, you mean exactly the same way, that is descripted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user?answertab=votes#125981) and what I've linked to in my initial post (http://i.stack.imgur.com/MsSyK.png). Right? So, as I've already said -- that does NOT work for admin users.

Comment: What makes your case `DSQUERY USER -name avex | DSGET USER -memberof -expand` thx!

Comment: That provide effective law. Do not redefined LSDOU? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277394.aspx

Comment: The commandos dsquery and dsget cannot be found. avex ist administrator (group "administrators").

Comment: LSDOU? "It’s group policy inheritance model, where the policies are applied to Local machines, Sites, Domains and Organizational Units." (http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/Computer-Security-2/_What_is_LSDOU_.html) Right? I think, I have not changed it.

Comment: Can you create symlinks (e.g. `mklink /D linkfolder targetfolder`) on your system as admin user? I don't mean the case, when you're working on CMD, after you have opened it with the option "Start programm as Administrator". I mean, when you are logged in as a user of the group " Administrators" and use/start CMD (or another programm, that you create a symlink with) "normally".