# How to create aliases in windows

Tags: windows-7

In Linux I can do this :

```
 ln -s /tmp/mydocs /home/user/docs/
```

it will create alias to  **/home/user/docs/** and I can access to docs with `cd /tmp/mydocs/`

In windows :

I have this directory **c:\users\user1\docs\**

i want to create shortcut named **mydocs**, so i can access to docs directory  by `cd mydocs`

is this possible??

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/548829/symlinks-for-admin-users-on-windows/548854#548854

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux you can use `ln` command to create symbolic link, but in Windows you have to use `mklink` command to create symbolic links:

> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

```
    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
            refers to.
```

Tip: Symbolic link just works on **NTFS** file system and Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008.

Comment: +1 for answering with `MKLINK`. I got tired of looking at answers that recommend `DOSKEY`.