# Can't create symlink on Windows VM's mapped network drive

Tags: virtual-machine, filesystems, windows-server-2008, symbolic-link, mklink

I have a Server 2008 VM (Parallels 9), and I share a folder from OSX via a mapped network drive "`T:`".

I am trying to make a symlink from one folder on `T:` to another folder on the same drive, like so:

```
T:\> mklink /d foo bar
```

After working out all the permissions issues, a la [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user), I have discovered that Windows doesn't like the filesystem (`PrlSF`).

Is there a way to create a Windows-recognized symlink there?

I have tried

- making the symlink in OSX (Explorer calls it a "File," and it plays all sorts of merry havoc with the `dir` list.)
- `mklink /d C:\foo bar`, which makes a link, but file permissions are impossible to set.
- `mklink /d foo C:\bar`, which gives the same error:

  > The device does not support symbolic links.

Comment: The share is actually on the OSX box?

Comment: Yes. `T:` is a mapping to `\\psf\share`, which is a "network drive" created by Parallels of a folder in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

> "...the functionality enabling cross-host symbolic links requires that the remote system also support them, which effectively limits their support to Windows Vista and later Windows operating systems." --[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

It looks like `mklink` is tolerant of other file systems, unlike a junction, as long as Windows can read it. If it's a network share, it's using (essentially) Network File System (NFS) over Samba (SMB), so it can even read proprietary file systems.