# How do I give myself privilege to create symbolic links on Windows 7 logged in as domain user?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, uac, privileges

I would like to be able to use mklink without the inconvenience of right-clicking on cmd.exe and choosing "Run as Administrator". I am logged in at work as a domain user with local admin privileges, and UAC is enabled.

I have added the following to "Create Symbolic Links" in "User Rights Assignment" in Local Security Policy: Administrators, Users, OURDOMAIN\MyUsername.

I then logged out and back in.

When I type WHOAMI /PRIV it still doesn't show SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege.

What am I doing wrong (or failing to do)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create symbolic links in Windows 8.1 without an admin command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/839580/how-can-i-create-symbolic-links-in-windows-8-1-without-an-admin-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a symbolic link on a local directory, then it's possible domain policy is overriding the local policy you set.

Comment: Thanks, Wohlfe. Yes, I'm trying to creates purely local symlinks - to a file in my own directory on my C: drive. So is there anything I can do other than ask the network administrator to give me the privilege through a domain policy, even though this is just for use on my local machine?

Answer (score -3):

Setting *Create Symbolic Link* privilege in Secpol has no effect if your user is in the Administrator group.  This has been answered in quite a few places already.
Here's one:
[How can I create symbolic links in Windows 8.1 without an admin command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/839580/how-can-i-create-symbolic-links-in-windows-8-1-without-an-admin-command-prompt/839608#839608)

Comment: Wrong like everywhere. It has effect if you add yourself by name in the list of permitted users, it does not matter if you are part of the Administrators group. BUT just adding the Administrators group does not work.