# mklink demands administrative privileges despite secpol.msc's "create symbolic links" permission being set and despite running cygwin's editrights

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, mklink

This is not a duplicate , because I tried the solution here [How do I create a link in Windows 7 home premium as a regular user?](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user)  and another solution too that I mention, and it didn't work and i'm asking what to do when that doesn't work.

I am running Windows 7

Here you see I get the message that I don't have sufficient privileges to do mklink.  I'd like to be able to do it without running cmd as administrator.

```
C:\Users\har>echo %userprofile%
C:\Users\har

C:\Users\har>
C:\Users\har>echo dsfdsfsd >ffff

C:\Users\har>mklink lsomefile ffff
You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.

C:\Users\har>
```

So I set "Create Symbolic Links" to include Everyone as well as my username. as described here [How do I create a link in Windows 7 home premium as a regular user?](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user)

[image]

That didn't work, I still get that message.

And I tried a solution mentioned here http://blog.rlucas.net/rants/dont-bother-with-symlinks-in-windows-7/

And I tried this editrights command from cygwin, from cmd run as administrator(where editrights gives no error).

You do `$editrights -a SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege -u [USERNAME]` so in my case

```
$editrights -a SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege -u har
```

And I have restarted.

But it doesn't work I still get that message that I "do not have sufficient privilege"

Answer (score 1):

If your user is in the Administrator security group then this setting has no effect: [How can I create symbolic links in Windows 8.1 without an admin command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/839580/how-can-i-create-symbolic-links-in-windows-8-1-without-an-admin-command-prompt/839608#839608)

Other options:
- remove yourself from Administrators (I wouldn't do this)
- Enable Developer mode Windows 10 (no mucking with sec policies, it just works)
- The option mentioned in the posts above, I haven't tried that so I have no in site to it's effectiveness.

Comment: User is using Windows 7 not Windows 8.1 or Windows 10

Comment: You could point out that from vista onwards, "If your user is in the Administrator security group then this setting has no effect:"  the link you mention https://superuser.com/questions/839580/how-can-i-create-symbolic-links-in-windows-8-1-without-an-admin-command-prompt/839608   mentions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320550/why-is-secreatesymboliclinkprivilege-ignored-on-windows-8 whose answers mentions vista onwards, so including windows 7.     Your second paragraph is interesting but, as you suggest,  only applies to windows 10.