# 7Zip Cannot create symbolic link, access is denied to libhdfs.so and libhadoop.so

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, 7-zip, hadoop

I am working on Windows 10 and trying to install Hadoop

I downloaded it [from here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/).

When trying to extract Hadoop for files (`libhdfs.so` and `libhadoop.so`) I am getting the error.

`Cannot create symbolic link : Access is denied`

[image]

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Are you running as an Administrator?

Comment: Note to install hadoop on Windows you need to download the source and build it yourself. [Build and Install Hadoop 2.x or newer on Windows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows)

Comment: @DavidPostill admin did it - had to run 7Zip as app. Thanks

Comment: Great! Added as answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### How do I fix this?

> I am getting the error: "Cannot create symbolic link : Access is denied"

You need to run 7-Zip File Manager in administrator mode.

Right-click the icon of 7-Zip File Manager, and then click "Run as administrator".

Comment: Worked, but why do you need admin to create symlinks on Windows?

Comment: @Timmmm You don't necessarily need admin but you do need a special privilege: See [How do I create a link in Windows 7 home premium as a regular user?](https://superuser.com/a/125981)

Comment: @DavidPostill is this answer applicable to Windows 7?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Err yes. See my comment above.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer is not really correct, although possibly may work in some scenarios, is not the reason "why", and privilege doesn't really apply here.

The problem is going to arise in most scenarios when unpacking a .tar.gz or other similar non-Windows file-system format. The problem is due to the order in which the files are being unpacked. In Linux for example, "dangling sym-links" are permitted, therefore no error occurs, and everything works fine, but on Windows, that is not the case. It is unpacking and trying to create a symbolic link to a file that does not yet exists, which is not permitted.

Forcing it may unpack the files in some situations, or may unpack them but they will be of 0 size. Extracting multiple times MAY fix the issue in other situations, depending on how they were packed, or manual extraction in the correct order.

For 100% success, unpack them on a system that permits symbolic links to non-existent files (i.e. Linux, or the system the file was intended for.

This is not a "permission" issue, but an OS one. You are not going to see this error on files that were packaged on the file-system you are using, only on files intended for "foreign" operating system, like `.tar.gz`, `.dmg`, etc.

Comment: Do you think there's any way that 7ZIP could work around that issue if a bug report was made?

Comment: @Pikamander2 It would probably be possible, likely involve some sort of sorting and resolving of symlinks before packing, though attempting to do so may introduce another new set of problems altogether, as this is going beyond the scope of a compression program. Symlinks between the systems work vastly differently, as well as the file systems. There are also certain things that are possible to do in one system, and not in others (even just between Windows versions). It is likely this will break more than it will fix, and best to just leave it to the user to ensure correctness.