# How do I grant myself permission to make symbolic links on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, windows-8.1

I am trying to figure out how to grant myself permission to make symbolic links as a non-administrator on Windows 8.1 (NOT Windows 8.1 Pro) which lacks gpedit.msc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not joined to a domain, you can use `secpol.msc`.

1. Press <kbd>Start</kbd>
2. type **secpol.msc**
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Computer configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment → Create symbolic links

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Dmytro Bondarchuk's suggestion](https://web.archive.org/web/20220329015654/https://dbondarchuk.com/2016/09/23/adding-permission-for-creating-symlink-using-powershell/) (indicated by [Nikita Malyavin](https://superuser.com/users/695737/nikita-malyavin) in [[image]this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1177067/35758)), it appears we can use [`secedit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit) with PowerShell native commands to add the symbolic links permissions to the user.

```pwsh
function Add-SymLinkPermissions {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $UserAccount = $env:USERNAME
    )
    Write-Host 'Checking SymLink permissions...'
    $sidstr = $null
    if ( "$accountToAdd" -eq 'Everyone' ) {
        $sidstr = 'S-1-1-0'
    }
    else {
        try {
            $NtPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "$UserAccount"
            $sid = $NtPrincipal.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
            $sidstr = $sid.Value.ToString()
        }
        catch {
            $sidstr = $null
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Account: $($UserAccount)" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($sidstr) ) {
        throw [System.ArgumentException]::new('UserAccount', 'UserAccount is not valid')
    }
    Write-Host "Account SID: $($sidstr)" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    $tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Write-Host 'Export current Local Security Policy' -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    secedit.exe /export /cfg "$($tmp)" 
    $c = Get-Content -Path $tmp 
    $currentSetting = ''
    foreach ($s in $c) {
        if ( $s -like 'SECreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege*') {
            $x = $s.split('=', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
            $currentSetting = $x[1].Trim()
        }
    }
    if ( $currentSetting -notlike "*$($sidstr)*" ) {
        Write-Host 'Need to add permissions to SymLink' -ForegroundColor Yellow

        Write-Host 'Modify Setting "Create SymLink"' -ForegroundColor DarkCyan

        if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($currentSetting) ) {
            $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr)"
        }
        else {
            $currentSetting = "*$($sidstr),$($currentSetting)"
        }
        Write-Host "$currentSetting"
        $outfile = @"
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[Version]
signature="`$CHICAGO`$"
Revision=1
[Privilege Rights]
SECreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege = $currentSetting
"@
        $tmp2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
        Write-Host 'Import new settings to Local Security Policy' -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        $outfile | Set-Content -Path $tmp2 -Encoding Unicode -Force
        Push-Location (Split-Path $tmp2)
        try {
            secedit.exe /configure /db 'secedit.sdb' /cfg "$($tmp2)" /areas USER_RIGHTS 
        }
        finally { 
            Pop-Location
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'NO ACTIONS REQUIRED! Account already in "Create SymLink"' -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        Write-Host "Account $UserAccount already has permissions to SymLink" -ForegroundColor Green
        return $true
    }
}
```

I have gathered the relevant parts into this [[image: GitHub Logo] Gist](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/68c1084c5ae12f2288442e9286d51802).

```pwsh
<# Grant SymLink rights PowerShell function from Gist #> 
iex (New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mavaddat/68c1084c5ae12f2288442e9286d51802/raw/65374381b3dbbfadaea3b358a642a262c773eb59/grantSymLinkRights.ps1')  
<# Add symlink Rights (requires admin UAC) #> 
Add-SymLinkPermissions -UserAccount $env:USERNAME
```

Result:

```sh
Checking SymLink permissions...
Account:    ██████████
Account SID: S-█-█-██-██████████-██████████-█████████-██████
Export current Local Security Policy

The task has completed successfully.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info.
Need to add permissions to SymLink
Modify Setting "Create SymLink"
*S-█-█-██-██████████-██████████-█████████-██████,*S-█-█-██-███
Import new settings to Local Security Policy

The task has completed successfully.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info.
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

> Polsedit is a utility to modify user policies such as user account rights and user privileges on a local or remote system. This can be useful when for some reason you are unable ro [sic] run `secpol.msc` snap-in, for example, XP Home and Vista Home do not have `secpol.msc` at all.
>
> <sub>Source: [Southsoftware Products](http://www.southsoftware.com/)</sub>

1. Download [Polsedit](http://www.southsoftware.com/downloads.html), and extract its archive somewhere.
2. Launch the 32-bit or 64-bit version, depending on your [operating system bitness](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us). The program requires administrator rights.
3. Right-click the **Create symbolic links** policy (the list is sorted alphabetically), and choose **Properties** from the context menu.
4. Click the **Add User or Group** button, select the target account, and click **OK**.
5. Repeat step 4 for any other required user or group. Click the **Close** button, and exit the program. The changes become effective next time the selected account(s) log on.

### Further reading

- [Create symbolic links](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221947.aspx)

Comment: You're suggesting people download a random external tool [flagged by at least one vendor as malicious](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/149c3578103f43482f013238cd4fc0db354a862d9acffdbe9c2c2f0e80a8f794) from an unaccredited website belonging to an unknown company with spelling mistakes in its own software description to manage their computer security policy?